# AutoMapper Queryable Extension ProjectTo Child object / Property expansion not working

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I am new to AutoMapper and am trying to use the ProjectTo extension, but I guess I'm missing something.

For example I created a simple AspNetCore project to test with.
Configuring AutoMapper in the Startup.cs ConfigureServices.

```
services.AddAutoMapper(this.GetType().Assembly);
```

I have these model classes:

```
public class PersonDTO
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string AddressStreetName { get; set; }
    public string AddressStreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string AddressCityName { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public string StreetName { get; set; }
    public string StreetNumber { get; set; }
    public string CityName { get; set; }
}

public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

I then also created this Profile:

```
public class PersonProfile : Profile
{
    public PersonProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Person, PersonDTO>().ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Then creating the DTO:

```
var personDTO = new PersonDTO()
{
    Name = "John",
    AddressStreetName = "TestStraat",
    AddressStreetNumber = "10",
    AddressCityName = "TestCity"
};
```

Using the mapper works perfectly:

```
var personFromPersonDTO = _mapper.Map<Person>(personDTO);
```

The Address property is set.

Using ProjectTo:

```
var list = new List<PersonDTO>();
    list.Add(personDTO);
    var listPersons = list
        .AsQueryable()
        .ProjectTo<Person>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider, m=>m.Address)
        .ToList();
```

The object is mapped in the new list, but Address property is null.
What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using `ProjectTo`, some type matching needs to be done. You can refer to this example.

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var personDTO = new PersonDTO()
        {
            Name = "John",
            AddressStreetName = "TestStraat",
            AddressStreetNumber = "10",
            AddressCityName = "TestCity"
        };
        var personFromPersonDTO = mapper.Map<Person>(personDTO);
        var list = new List<PersonDTO>();
        list.Add(personDTO);
     
        //Configure mapping relationship
        var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        cfg.CreateMap<PersonDTO, Person>()
        .ForMember(p => p.Name, conf => conf.MapFrom(ol => ol.Name))
        .ForMember(p => p.Address, conf => conf.MapFrom(o => new Address
        {
            CityName = o.AddressCityName,
            StreetName = o.AddressStreetName,
            StreetNumber = o.AddressStreetNumber
        }))
        );
        var modelList=list.AsQueryable().ProjectTo<Person>(configuration);
        return Ok(modelList);
    }
```

It will get the result.

[image]