# automapper issue in nested entity

Tags: model-view-controller, nested, entity-framework-core, linq-to-entities, automapper

Entity:

```
public class AccountEntity: MasterEntity
     {
    
    public AccountType AccountType { get; set; }
    public DepartmentEntity Department { get; set; }
    public string LeadSource { get; set; }
    public ResourceEntity AccountManager { get; set; }
    public AccountQualificationStatus QualificationStatus { get; set; }
  }

  public class DepartmentEntity : MasterEntity
  {
  }
   public class ResourceEntity : MasterEntity
    {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    }
   public abstract class MasterEntity: Entity
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
   }

 Model

 public class Accounts
   {
    private string depname;
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Code { get; set; }
    public string AccountType { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
   }
    public AccountMappingProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Account, AccountTest>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Opportunity, OpportunityEntity>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Accounts, AccountEntity>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Resource, ResourceEntity>().ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Projects, ProjectEntity>().ReverseMap();
        
    }

       public static class AccountMapper
     {
       private static readonly Lazy<IMapper> Lazy = new Lazy<IMapper>(() =>
      {
           var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {

            cfg.ShouldMapProperty = p => p.GetMethod.IsPublic || p.GetMethod.IsAssembly;
            cfg.AddProfile<AccountMappingProfile>();
        });
        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
        return mapper;
    });

      public static IMapper Mapper => Lazy.Value;
   }
```

I am able to fetch resource details .while I am fetching accounts with department and resources, the value for department is giving me null after automapping.

```
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Accounts>> GetAccounts()
    {
        try
        {
        var accounts = await _context.Account.Include(c=>c.Director).ToListAsync();
            
           // accounts = await _context.Account.Include(c => c.Department).ToListAsync();

    return AccountMapper.Mapper.Map<List<Accounts>>(accounts);
  }
         }
```

controller method:

```
   public async Task<IEnumerable<Accounts>> GetClients()
    {
        var result = await _repository.GetAccounts();
        return result;
    }
```

if I am uncommenting the code to include department, its is giving the object name.
I need to get the department details as well. how can i get that.Department entity is inheriting master entity.

Comment: You need `ProjectTo` instead. Check http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html.

Comment: dbContext.Courses.ProjectTo<CourseModel>(Config, new Dictionary<string, object> { {"currentUserName", Request.User.Name} });        ==> is this the one? could you p[lease give somemore details on this. how to define variable config

Comment: @Reshma, about prjectto, you can refer to this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64896786/automapper-queryable-extension-projectto-child-object-property-expansion-not-w/64929736#64929736).